# Landau Ginzburg path integral (PI) for the Ising model at gaussian order

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, path-integral, ising-model, effective-field-theory

I am stick with a problem in computing explicitely the gaussian PI in the Landau-Ginzburg  theory for the Ising model.
If we do a procedure of coarse graining, we can define $m(x)$ as a continuous field defined in each point of the lattice; the PI is given by the sum over all spin configuration which give rise to the same magnetization $m(x)$, integrated over all the possible m(x):

$$\int dm(x) \sum_{\{s_i\}}e^{-\beta H\{s_i\}}.$$

Since the sum is very hard the passage is to substitute the "microscopic hamiltonian" with the effective LG free energy

$$H\{m(x)\}= \int d^Dx [(\frac{1}{2}\nabla m(x))^2+r_0 m^2(x)+\frac{v_0}{4!}m^4(x)]$$ where $r_0\simeq (T-T_c), v_0>0.$

Since we are in the LG I go on using $m(x)=m_0+\mathcal{\delta}m(x)$ in the free energy and retaining only gaussian order i arrive to:

$$\mathcal Z = e^{-H(m_0)}\int d\mathcal{\delta}m(x) e^{-\frac{\beta}{2}[(\nabla \mathcal{\delta}m(x))^2+a\mathcal{\delta}^2m(x)]}$$

where $e^{-H(m_0)}$ is the saddle point contribution given by configurations of $m(x)=m_0$ of the "pure" Landau theory, and $a$ is a value that contains $r_0$ and $v_0$ that comes out from the expansion.
Since the integral has this mysterious measure that we cannot (at least me) interpret, we write everything in terms of discrete fourier transforms

$$\mathcal{\delta}m(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_{k}(e^{ik\cdot x}\mathcal{\delta}m_k).$$

If we transform everything in the integral the PI can be rewritten as a "tower of integration over the modes":

$$\mathcal{Z}=e^{-\beta H(m_0)}\Pi_k [ \int d\mathcal{\delta}m_k d(\mathcal{\delta}m_k)^* e^{-\frac{\beta}{2}(k^2+a)|\mathcal{\delta}m(x)|^2}].$$

This notes were taken during my statistical physics course, and they inspire to Tong's statistical field theory notes.
Assuming that the steps were done without error, I would like to know how to arrive at the final result suggested by my prof:
$$\mathcal{Z}=e^{-\beta H(m_0)}\Pi_k \frac{2\pi}{\beta (k^2+a)}.$$
This has to be done using gaussian integration (we retained only quadratic terms in order to do so), but i do not understand how to do it in practice. One must also use the "reality condition for the "fluctuation field": $\mathcal({\delta}m_k)^*={\delta}m_{-k}$.

any comment is welcome :)

Comment: One way: with \mathcal({\delta}m_k)^*={\delta}m_{-k} we could write down the integral as $\prod_{k>0} \int d ({\rm Re}\delta m_k ) d ({\rm Im}\delta m_k ) e^{...}$